# File system goes read-only when using file explorers

Tags: mount, filesystem, files, system, read-only

I have a problem with my 15.10 system and it goes as follows:

When using Nemo or Nautilus (these are the two I've tried) works fine as long as I explore my home directory only.

Visiting 'File System' (root directory) and then 'Home' again, the file system goes read-only.

I could imagine that it might be a problem related to temp files or privileges?

Any experiences or suggestions regarding this issue?

I'm using Gnome desktop and the Home directory is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your filesystem is slightly corrupted. The usual culprit is an unclean shutdown.

When you use a file explorer it tries to access one of the corrupted directories, the kernel discovers the corruption and remounts it read-only.

To verify whether this is the case open a command line immediately after the filesystem becomes read-only and type `dmesg | tail`. You will likely see hints about what is going on.

I would suggest to issue command `sudo touch /forcefsck` and then reboot. This will force check and repair of your root filesystem and your problem will likely go away.

Answer (score 0):

You should only have read-only access to `/home`. User files are stored in `/home/<user>` (replace `<user>` with your username). It's part of why Unix/Linux is more secure than other operating systems. Open the `Home` directory, and you will see an icon for the right directory.

BTW, when you are logged in, your encrypted home directory has a decrypted version mounted over it, so you can read/write your files.